# Pointer to member function - syntax

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
void foo();
class Foomatic() {
    void bar();
    void baz()
    {
        std::thread a(foo); // this compiles
        std::thread b(Foomatic::bar, this); // this doesn't 
        std::thread c(&Foomatic::bar, this); // and this compiles
        // ...
    }
};
```

I know that the correct syntax for the pointer to member function is `&Foomatic::bar`.

But why exactly is `Foomatic::bar` incorrect? What does that one return? And why exactly is the `&Foomatic::bar` the correct one? It seems counter-intuitive to me.

This is not a duplicate. The question you linked to answers what the correct syntax is, not explaining the reasons why.

I'm asking why C++ is so inconsistent here, I already know what the syntax is.

Comment: @Ed Heal: This is not a duplicate. I'm asking not, what the correct syntax is, because I know what it is, but **why** is the correct syntax correct. The answers only say what the correct syntax is.

Comment: The answer is tautological. The syntax is incorrect because the language specification says so. Why is a soccer match 90 minutes long? Because that's what the rules say.

Comment: Perhaps the real question is why `a(foo)` works, when it should have been `a(&foo)`?

Comment: @BoPersson Seeing this from this point, it's a good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ inherited the conversion from functions to function pointers from C: in C you could just assigne a function name to a function pointer without the need to take the address. This "decay" of function names to function pointers seems somewhat ill-advised and did cause some confusion in C.

When pointers to members where introduced there was no need to be backward compatible with C: C doesn't have pointers to members. Thus, there was the option to not have an implicit conversion from a member name to a pointer to member. Since a facility can be added later if it feels necessary but hardly removed the choice was made to not have an implicit conversion from a member name to pointer to member.

Since there is a reasonably consistent interface to get pointers to functions, pointers to members, and pointers to objects there doesn't seem to be a need to have implicit conversions from member names to pointer to member pretty much as there is no implicit conversion from an object name to a pointer to an object.

Semantically, something like `T::member` is a reference to a member rather than pointer to a member. However, I don't think it is possible to formulate this type with the current specification. Possibly, a future standard defines someting for this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If `&Foomatic::Bar` is a pointer-to-member function (because you're taking the *address* of the function using the address-of operator `&`), then `Foomatic::Bar` is a *member function*, not a pointer-to-member function.

This is exactly the same with non-member functions: if `&foo` is a pointer to (non-member) function, then `foo` is a function.

Neither C++ nor C have functions as first-class objects, e.g., you can't have a variable whose type/value is a function --- only a pointer thereto.

As a syntactic sugar special case for non-member functions, you can call said function without having to deference it first explicitly, e.g, `foo(42)` is a short-hand for `(*foo)(42)` if `foo` is a pointer to (non-member) function.